# How to encrypt with both the private key and public key

Tags: bash, encryption, ssh, openssl

I have this bash script

```
#generate key
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in key.pem -text -noout
#save public key in pub.pem file
openssl rsa -in key.pem -pubout -out pub.pem
openssl rsa -in pub.pem -pubin -text -nout
#encrypt data
openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey pub.pem -pubin -in license.json -out license_encrypted.json
#decrypt data
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey key.pem -in license_encrypted.json
```

In the code you can see I encrypt the file using the public key and decrypt using the private key, I need to know how to encrypt using both the private key and the public key. Is this possible. Should I decrypt using the private key or can idecrypt using the public key, this is in regards to software licenses I am trying to encrypt

Comment: probably gonna get down voted for asking this

Comment: or can I as alternative encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key, the license holder will have public key and server will have private key

Comment: i found this on another post "Asymmetric means you cannot use the same key for decryption that you used for encryption. Code signing is one scenario where you encrypt using the private key. Recipients of the code can then use their public key to verify if the code was unchanged." makes a little more sense now

Comment: the wole idea is that I need to encrypt a license file with license information and a client needs to be the only one allowed to decrypt that license information

Comment: found the answer I was looking for just removed -pubin from encrypting statement

Comment: When you want to ***encrypt with the private key***, you often want a ***signature scheme with recovery***. That would probably work for you in a DRM/license key scheme. Otherwise, *encrypt with the private key* is not a valid cryptographic operation. I don't think the question was -3 or -4 worthy. I think you don't know what to ask for, and the people moving against you don't realize what you are asking for, so you got an upvote from me to offset the down votes.

Comment: Ya this stuff is not that easy to understand so I was merely probing for any type of information to understand what I needed, Sorry if my questions where unclear and confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know how to encrypt using both the private key and the public key.

This makes no sense.

In public key cryptography, every party has a key pair composed of a public key and a private key.  To encrypt a message for someone, you use his public key; he'll then use his private key to decrypt the message.

Your client should therefore generate a key pair once (preferably, this should be done automatically) and then send you his public key, with which you'll encrypt the license file and send it back to him.

Comment: yes that makes sense I was looking for clarity on this, before I can do any code I needed to understand it fully thanks

Comment: So for example if I want to generate the keys myself on a web application for managing licenses, how would I go about, basically do the clients have to generate keys their side, or can I do it for them. Like I create a license attach key to it so the information on the license is encrypted and they then access that license with their key

Comment: Im really not trying to get complicated just trying to understand fully

Comment: Yes, the client has to generate the key pair on his side, otherwise you'd have the problem of how to give him securely his private key.  But do you really need the license to be encrypted?

Comment: It is a requirement, the license tells the person what their software can do or what it is entitled to do, it is just a way of making sure that clients cannot use any other features of the system

Comment: and basically a way of us being able to manage our clients software usage, and how to bill them etc

Comment: Yes, I know how a license works, but why do you need to *encrypt* it? Are you afraid it will be intercepted in transit? It looks like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: we do not want the licenses to be changed at any point, exactly

Comment: I agree it is an uneccessary complication, but thats the requirements for the development

Comment: "we do not want the licenses to be changed at any point" Looks like you want to preserve integrity of the license, not confidentiality. If this is the case you need to **sign** it, not encrypt it.

Comment: how can I sign it can you point me somewhere

Comment: I'd recommend that you start to learn the basics: symmetric vs asymmetric encryption, public and private key, signing, encryption, decryption, etc.  There are several tutorials on the web, just google for it; Wikipedia is also a good starting point.  Once you've understood these concepts fully you can start studying how openssl works.  Good luck! :)